# How can I handle web deployments (File System) when using EF6 (Database First)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have 3 DB environments:

- Dev
- QA
- Prod

I created my first MVC site which is utilizing EF6 (Database first).

Do I need to update my model and create a deployment files for each environment  or am I fine creating my model from one of the DB's (either Dev or qa) and using the same deployment files?

I cannot guarantee that all 3 environments are the same.

Answer (score 0):

in package manager console type this for the first migration

```
 update-database -scrpit
```

and after that you can use

```
 update-database -scrpit -SourceMigration:[yourMigrationClassName]
```

This will generate sql script for all migrations in your application. You can the run this script on your destination db.

i would suggest you to use "codefirst from DB" instead of "Database first".
Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526739/6811559)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: All DB scripts are generated by our DB team.  I can only roll my project at the same time the DB team rolls any db changes.

Comment: you should make sure all your generated models, methods match to corresponding tables, functions and stored procure in the destination db. if not you will end up having errors. You can use the same deployment files unless the above conditions are met. Managing migrations is a pain in DBFirst.  Note: do not change name of the connection string in the web.config. You can create different web.config for each environments using configuration manager.

Comment: OK.  So in my case there may be times where I will need separate deployments. (i.e. Changes in dev/qa but not yet in prod)